# Terraform: How to iterate the name or another variable in a resource group when the variable being passed in is a list of a list of maps?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

This is what I have so far, while I can pull a specific list or name using the local variables, I am having trouble transitioning this into the resource group. First, am I attempting this the right way? If not how can I iterate on the name for the subnet so that the subnets belonging to the respective vnet map are added?

```js
variable "vnets" {
  default = [
    {
      vnet_name     = "test-vnet"
      address_space = "10.250.0.0"
      network_size  = 16
      subnets = [
        {
          name                     = "first-subnet"
          network_security_group   = "first-nsg"
          security_group_rules = [
            {
              name                       = "first-sg"
              priority                   = 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name                     = "second-subnet"
          network_security_group   = "second-nsg"
          security_group_rules = [
            {
              name                       = "second-sg"
              priority                   = 100
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


locals {
   
   subnet_names = { 
         for vnet in var.vnets[*]:
           (vnet.vnet_name) =>  vnet.subnets[*].name
   }
   
   security_group_names = flatten(var.vnets[*].subnets[*].security_group_rules[*].name)

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  count               = length(var.vnets)
  #??? name                      = locals.subnet_names[count.index].subnets.name
 
  
  resource_group_name       = data.azurerm_resource_group.network_group.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.vnets.*.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to flatten your `subnet_names`:

```
locals {
   
   subnet_names = { 
         for vnet in var.vnets[*]:
           (vnet.vnet_name) =>  vnet.subnets[*].name
   }
   
   security_group_names = flatten(var.vnets[*].subnets[*].security_group_rules[*].name)
   

   # uniqueness of "${vnet}-${subnet}" pairs is assumed. it will not work
   # if the pairs are not unique
   subnet_names_flat = merge([
         for vnet, subnets in local.subnet_names:
           {
             for subnet in subnets:          
               "${vnet}-${subnet}" => {name = vnet, subnet = subnet}
           }
         ]...)
     
}
```

Which will result in `subnet_names_flat` being:

```
{
  "test-vnet-first-subnet" = {
    "name" = "test-vnet"
    "subnet" = "first-subnet"
  }
  "test-vnet-second-subnet" = {
    "name" = "test-vnet"
    "subnet" = "second-subnet"
  }
}
```

Then your `azurerm_subnet.subnets` could as below. However, I'm **not able to verify correctness** of your the `azurerm_subnet`, thus you may need to change it further. But the idea is to iterate over `local.subnet_names_flat`, which makes the `for_each` very easy to use:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {

  for_each                 = local.subnet_names_flat
  
  name                      = each.value.subnet  
  resource_group_name       = data.azurerm_resource_group.network_group.name
  virtual_network_name      = each.value.vnet
  address_prefixes          = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}
```

Comment: hey @Marcin, this works for simple use case like the example. But I am hesitant to use it for the long run, because what if my subnet list of maps grows, then now my locals resource is growing, because i have to break down each new variable. Thoughts?

Comment: @shan Your `variable.vnets` is complex. Its easy for you to read it, but difficult to use it in `for_each` or `count`. The use of locals transforms it to TF friendly form. You can reduce the amount of locals if it is going to grow. In your example, you can eliminate `local.subnet_names` and just have `subnet_names_flat`. If you don't want locals at all, you would have to embed the flattening expressions directly in the resource definitions. The alternative is to modify `variable.vnets` to be easier to work with from the get go. So you have to decide which way is most suited for your scenario.

Comment: my thoughts exactly on the last part, maybe restructure the variables.vnets to work better. But any suggestion on how I would go about restructuring that? I know this might be off topic a bit, but hoping to get some insight. ty

Comment: @shan Sadly its difficult for me to advise on restructuring, as I'm not sure how it would be used in your resources. I'm more into AWS, thus I am not sure know exactly subnets in azure are constructed. You can always make new question specific to the restructuring issue.

Comment: thanks. Will mark this right as it still does the job at a basic level. Created new question for what I need. cheers